# Kicking off an event after multiple objects updated in Hibernate transaction

Tags: hibernate, event-listener

I have a Hibernate project with entities having a similar relationship to the following:

```
Car {
    String name;
    Engine engine;
}

Engine {
    String name;
}
```

We have an external system (web services, a black box) which needs to be updated with changes made to the above entities, however, the external system does not make the distinction between a `Car` and an `Engine`:

```
RemoteCar {
    String name;
    String engineName;
}
```

The synchronisation process involves getting an instance of `RemoteCar` from the remote system, updating the values that have changed from `Car` and `Engine`, and then sending an update request.

I am trying to use a `PostUpdateEventListener` with `requiresPostCommitHanding` returning `true` to kick off an application event to update the external system, but if both the `Car`'s name and the `Engine`'s name are updated in the same transaction, I receive two events, kicking off two synchronisations with the the external system.

Is there way to ensure that I only receive the events I need? Sadly some updates to `Engine` are performed directly (`EngineDao.get(1).setName()`), meaning that the `Car` is never involved - I can easily work my way back up the tree to get my `Car` instance, but I don't see how to tell whether an update to `Engine` is part of a larger update of `Car` or a self-contained update of `Engine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is not to synchronize with the remote system on each listener callback because for cases as you've mentioned, it becomes a potential I/O bottleneck.  Instead, I would suggest maintaining a transaction-specific cache and gets replicated once.

When the `PostUpdateEventListener` fires, do something like the following:

1. Check if the current transaction has a cache.  If it doesn't, create the cache and register a before commit transaction callback (more below).
2. For each update event, inspect the cache to see whether the appropriate `RemoteCar` has already been fetched.  If it has, simply update the cache accordingly.  If it isn't in the cache, fetch it from the remote system and update the cache instance.

During the commit phase of the transaction, the before commit transaction callback is fired which would iterate the cached instances and depending on your API, could send a bulk update (1 I/O call) to your remote system to update all modified `RemoteCar` instances.

This would allow your use case where 2 updates trigger 2 synchronization points to be reduced to a single remote fetch, 2 local updates, and 1 replication update back to the external system.

Comment: Thanks for this. How would you manage your cache? Could I use a Map with the value of PostUpdateEvent.getSession().getTransaction() as a key in an IdentityHashMap? (with proper synchronisation of course)

Comment: Yep, that is precisely what I do when managing the audit process cache related to a hibernate session within Envers.